# DJANGO not returning context in my html template

Tags: python, django

why this context not rendering in my html template:

```
 return render(request, 'index.html',{'message_name':name})
```

This context will print user name after successful submit my contact form. here is my code:

**views.py**

```
@csrf_exempt 
def home_view(request,*args,**kwargs):
    name = None
    if request.method == "POST":
       contact_form = ContactForm(request.POST)
       if contact_form.is_valid():
          
          name = request.POST['name'] 
          email = request.POST['email']
          subject = request.POST['subject']
          message = request.POST['message']
          save_details = Contact(name=name,email=email,subject=subject,message=message)
          save_details.save()
          return HttpResponseRedirect("http://127.0.0.1:8000/")
          return render(request, 'index.html',{'message_name':name}) 
       else:
          print("not submitted")
          
           

    else:
       contact_form = ContactForm()
         

    return render(request, 'index.html',{'form':contact_form})
```

**app urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from pages import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home_view, name="home"),
    
]
```

**root urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from pages import urls
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('pages.urls')),
    
]
```

**index.html**

```
            <!--===== CONTACT =====-->
            <section class="contact section" id="contact">
                <h2 class="section-title">Contact</h2>
 {% if message_name %}
                <div class="centerTest">
                     <h1> Thanks {{ message_name }} for your message. We will get back to you very soon</h1>  
                </div>
{% else %} 

                <div class="contact__container bd-grid">
                    <form action="#contact" method = "POST" class="contact__form">
                              
                        {% for error in  form.non_field_errors %}
                          <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                               {{ error }}
                          </div>
                        {% endfor %}
                        
                        <label>Name:</label>  
                        {{ form.errors.name }}
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name" class="contact__input" {% if form.is_bound %}value="{{ form.name.value }} {% endif %}">
                        <label>Email:</label>
                        {{ form.errors.email }}
                        <input type="mail" placeholder="Email" name="email" class="contact__input" {% if form.is_bound %}value="{{ form.email.value }} {% endif %}">
                        <label>Subject:</label>
                        {{ form.errors.subject }}
                        <input type="text" placeholder="optional" name="subject" class="contact__input" {% if form.is_bound %}value="{{ form.subject.value }} {% endif %}">
                        <label>Message:</label>
                        {{ form.errors.message }}
                        <textarea name="message" placeholder="message"  id="" cols="0" rows="10"   class="contact__input" >{% if form.is_bound %}{{ form.message.value }} {% endif %}</textarea>
                         
                        <input type="submit" value="Send" class="contact__button button">
{% endif %}
```

if I remove the  HttpResponseRedirect then it showing context in my html template
[image]

But the problem is it resubmitting my from again and again on refresh. After adding HttpResponseRedirect it stop resubmitting the form but not printing the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass context directly in redirect or HttpResponseRedirect in django. You need to be  use session method. Try this:

```
@csrf_exempt 
def home_view(request,*args,**kwargs):
    name = None
    if request.method == "POST":
       contact_form = ContactForm(request.POST)
       if contact_form.is_valid():
          
          name = request.POST['name'] 
          email = request.POST['email']
          subject = request.POST['subject']
          message = request.POST['message']
          save_details = Contact(name=name,email=email,subject=subject,message=message)
          save_details.save()
          request.session['name'] = name
          return redirect(home_view)
       else:
          print("not submitted")
          
           

    else:
       contact_form = ContactForm()
         

    return render(request, 'index.html',{'form':contact_form})
```

Pass this `{{ request.session.name }}` in your index.html for show your context.

Answer (score 1):

As a basic Python concept (and probably any other programming language), you cannot have two `return` sentences, one above the other in a function as the first one will make the second one unreachable.

Example:

```
def say_hello(name, age):
    return f"hello {name}"
    return f"your age is {age}"
```

If you execute this function, you will only get "hello john doe" as the second return statement is never executed.

In your case, if you keep the `return HttpResponseRedirect()`, the `return render()` will never be executed, therefore you will never see the context.

If you want to redirect the user to a specific route you should do it conditionally in order to have the chance to execute one `return` or the other.

Comment: Can you please  show me an example? I just need to show context in  the html page after redirect

Comment: how to show context in html redirect page in djago ?

Comment: You cannot have two return statement in one block of code i.e universal law for any coding language